# On a result about genus two pencils

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

I am reading the paper "Canonical models of surfaces of general type" by E. Bombieri. In the last section of this paper, there is a statement saying that surfaces with $K^2=1$ and $p_g=0$ do not have pencils of genus $2$, and there is no proof. Is there a proof of this statement?

Comment: Perhaps it is worth including Bombieri's footnote from the paper: "Our proof is too long to be inserted here; we hope to return to this argument in another paper."

Comment: You are right. But I really want to see this proof and I can not find the "another paper".

Comment: I think you should ask this question to Torsten Ekedahl (because of his paper "Canonical models of surfaces of general type in positive characteristic"). He is also active in MO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact it seems that the statement is not correct.

The paper [Calabri, Ciliberto, Mendes Lopes, 
Numerical Godeaux surfaces with an involution. 
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 359 (2007), no. 4] contains the classification of numerical Godeaux surfaces (i.e., minimal surfaces of general type with $K^2=1$ and $p_g=0$) that have an automorphism of order 2. The examples described in section 6 have a pencil of curves of genus 2 (cf.  Remark 6.3).

Comment: Thanks, rita. I remember that minimal surfaces of general type with $p_g=0$ and $K^2 \ge 3$ do not have genus two pencil. I just want to know the cases that when $K^2$ is smaller, which correspond the Numerical Godeaux or Campedelli surfaces.

I will check the paper you mentioned.

Comment: For numerical Campedelli, you can look at [Calabri, Mendes Lopes, Pardini,  Involutions on numerical Campedelli surfaces. Tohoku Math. J. (2) 60 (2008), no. 1, 1–22]. This is essentially a continuation of  the paper I referred to in the answer and in 3.5 you can find examples of (numerical) Campedelli surfaces  with a genus 2 pencil. 

Comment: I have another quick question, rita. It is about what I said before. I said that minimal surfaces of general type with $p_g=0$ and $K^2 \ge 3$ have no pencils of genus 2. Actually I do not know what the pencil means here. Does it mean a \emph{morphism} of fibration or just a \emph{rational map}?

Comment:  If the surfaces is minimal of general type and $|C|$ is a pencil  with base points such  the general $C$ is smooth of genus 2 then the index theorem gives $K^2= 1$. On the other hand, I do not know whether one could have a pencil with base points and such that the general $C$ is singular but has geometric genus 2.


Comment: Thanks, rita! I think the original statement should be in the Xiao's Lecture Notes. But I can not find the statement in the book. I knew it from papers written by other people where they used "PENCIL" not "fibration". So this is why I was confused with the precise statement. Do you know the precise statement of Xiao's result?

Comment: "pencil" is used both for "fibration onto a curve" and for "1-dimensional linear system". To the latter is associated a rational map to $P^1$.  I don't remember Xiao's result, sorry. Try checking the paper where he proves that the bicanonical image is a surface if $K^2>1$. 
 

Answer (score 3):

I do not know whether this result is true.

In fact G. Xiao in his book [Surfaces fibrees en courbes de genre deux, page 66](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Surfaces-Fibrees-Courbes-Lecture-Mathematics/dp/3540156623) claims that a surface of general type with $p_g=q=0$, $K^2=1$ and a pencil of curves of genus $2$ has been constructed by Oort and Peters in their paper [A Campedelli surface with torsiongroup $\mathbb{Z}/2$](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/1385725881900615). You should check their construction, since unfortunately I have not time to do it now.

Notice that Oort and Peter call "Campedelli surface" what is nowadays called "Numerical Godeaux surface" (i.e., a surface of general type with $p_g=q=0$, $K^2=1$); in fact, the name "Campedelli surface" is currently used for surfaces with $p_g=q=0$, $K^2=2$.

At any rate, the following is surely true:

> if $S$ is a minimal surface of general type with $p_g=q=0$ and $K^2=1$, then the *bicanonical pencil* $|2K_S|$ cannot be composed with a pencil of curves of genus $2$.

See the paper by Catanese and Pignatelli [Fibrations of low genus I](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012959306000437), Section 5. The proof given there is not based on Bombieri's paper, but  it uses a structure theorem for genus $2$ fibrations which involves vector bundles techniques.